# Why does SolidMechanicsStrain calculated inside a module give strange results?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method, solidmechanics

**Bug introduced in 13.0 and fixed in 13.1.0**

---

I am exploring the FE capabilities of Mathematica and trying a few solid mechanics problems with the aim of bringing them into my teaching. The problem is a simplified version of the coupled heat transfer equation for a bi-layer with different elastic properties and different thermal expansion properties in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html#775646651). Instead of coupling a heat transfer model to a bi-layer I just apply a fixed change in the temperature. The following code works well

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

bilayersimulation[alphab_, alphat_, eb_, et_, nu_, dT_, l_, h_, 
  width_, hf_] := 
 Module[{mesh, alpha, emod, vars, pars, pde, gammafixed, sol, strains,
    stresses, boundary}, 
  boundary = 
   ToBoundaryMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0, 0}, {l, 0, 0}, {l, width, 0}, {0, width, 
       0}, {0, 0, hf*h}, {l, 0, hf*h}, {l, width, hf*h}, {0, width, 
       hf*h}, {0, 0, h}, {l, 0, h}, {l, width, h}, {0, width, h}}, 
    "BoundaryElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 
         8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {5, 6, 10, 9}, {2, 3, 7, 
         6}, {6, 7, 11, 10}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {7, 8, 12, 11}, {4, 1, 5, 
         8}, {8, 5, 9, 12}}]}];
  mesh = ToElementMesh[boundary];
  (*Create spatially dependent elastic moduli and thermal expansion \
coefficients*)alpha = If[z <= hf*h, alphab, alphat];
  emod = If[z <= hf*h, eb, et];
  vars = {{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}};
  pars = <|"YoungModulus" -> emod, "PoissonRatio" -> nu, 
    "ThermalExpansion" -> alpha, "ThermalStrainTemperature" -> dT|>;
  pde = SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars] == {0, 0, 0};
  gammafixed = SolidFixedCondition[x == 0, vars, pars];
  sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, gammafixed}, {u, v, 
     w}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
  strains = 
   SolidMechanicsStrain[{{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, 
      z}}, <||>, sol];
  stresses = SolidMechanicsStress[vars, pars, strains];
  {sol, mesh, strains, stresses}]
```

I have included in this code the calculation of strains and stresses using 'SolidMechanicsStrain' and 'SolidMechanicsStress'.

For an example simulation with different elastic properties and identical expansion coefficients I get the following result:

```
out = bilayersimulation[0.02, 0.02, 1000000000, 2000000000, 0.3, 1, 10, 1,
    3, 0.5];

Show[{out[[2]]["Edgeframe"], 
  SliceContourPlot3D[out[[3]][[1, 1]], 
   out[[2]], {x, y, z} \[Element] out[[2]], 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   Contours -> 5]}]
```

[image: Strains inside Block]

I would have expected these strains to be around 0.02.

If I however use the output of my Module and then calculate the strains I get the following:

```
strains = 
 SolidMechanicsStrain[{{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, 
    z}}, <||>, out[[1]]];

Show[{out[[2]]["Edgeframe"], 
  SliceContourPlot3D[strains[[1, 1]], 
   out[[2]], {x, y, z} \[Element] out[[2]], 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   Contours -> 5]}]
```

This has the following plot:

[image: Strains plotted outside module]

Here we see strains being of the right order of magnitude (except at the boundary).

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You have given the function `bilayersimulation` but you make use of `simulationrun`. Also, you could give `pars` to the strain function in place of the <||> though that probably does not matter. Also, in the function you give the argument nu but do not set that up in the `pars` section.

Comment: I think I have fixed the errors now.

Comment: When you comment out your last row in the function, `(*stresses=SolidMechanicsStress[vars,pars,strains];*)` things work as expected. This means that SolidMechanicsStress is somehow overwriting the strains. If this is really the case then this is a serious bug. I'll need to investigate further and simplify this. This may take some time to resolve. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for reporting.

Comment: @user21 I figured it was a bug, but wanted to check that I wasn't doing anything stupid. Thanks for confirming. Should I also sent this to Wolfram?

Comment: No need to send it to WRI, I'll file a bug you already had enough trouble with it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Here is a first workaround: `SetSystemOptions[
 "FiniteElementOptions" -> "CacheInterpolationElements" -> False]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and will be fixed once version 13.1 is available. Until then the best workaround is to switch off element caching during interpolations.

```
SetSystemOptions[  "FiniteElementOptions" -> "CacheInterpolationElements" -> False]
```

Sorry about that.

Comment: Shall  $13.1$ be available in a month or two? +1.

Comment: @Artes, hard to say, not not in the next few weeks, more in a few month, maybe june, july-ish. But that's a very wild guess.